# Symfony's app_dev.php shows "half" source code

Tags: php, symfony, apache2.4

I downloaded it with composer. Tried to run with the PHPStorm's built in server and it does not load the toolbar (404).

Then I tried to run it with Apache, I copied my project to `/var/www/html` and then I went to `http://localhost/symfony_app/web/app_dev.php` in the browser.

What is strange is that it partially shows the source code (but without line breaks):

```
loadClassCache(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This file (complete) has the following source code:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

In the Apache error logs there is nothing, just restarts.

The app works OK with Symfony's built-in server, in port 8000

Comment: what is shown exactly when you're trying to reach the page under apache?

Comment: Seems like you do not have the PHP module installed or configured in Apache.

Comment: @cilefen but would I don't see all the code and instead I see from `loadClassCache()` (not even $kernel->loadClassCache())

Comment: @mmmm a white page with text without format, which is the one I described

Answer (score 0):

The same thing just happened to me on a new vagrant setup I made. Weirdest thing I've seen. It turns out I had installed php5, but not completely. I needed to install specifically the `libapache2-mod-php5` package in Ubuntu. Running this installed it for me in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

I don't know what system you're running on but it might be a missing php package like this that's the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

if you have apache2 and php installed and got this issue enable

```
mod_rewrite
```

you can do that with:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

in your terminal and restard apache